# Enabling multiple tenants using OWIN Active Directory bearer tokens

Tags: active-directory, owin, adal

I've recently started playing with Azure Active Directory to authenticate users against my website built on AngularJS.

Using blogs and [sample code on GitHub](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/SinglePageApp-DotNet), I've gotten it working with single-tenant using a combination of [ADAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) and Katana's [Bearer Token AD integration](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory/WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationExtensions.cs).

However, I'm now running into some issues with supporting multiple tenants.

I've got a page set up that displays the user as ADAL sees them (found through the root scope's `userInfo`), as well as makes a call to my server that gets picked up by OWIN, and serializes `context.Authentication.User`.

Client-side, everything seems to be working properly. I can log in with any of my tenants, and it gives me the object I'd expect (with `isAuthenticated: true`, `username` populated, and all sorts of properties on `profile` describing the user, login, and tenant).

This is accomplished client-side by leaving off the `tenant` argument to my `adalAuthenticationServiceProvider.init` call, as described in the documentation.

Server-side, however, the `UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication` method doesn't like having no value for `Tenant` (in that it throws an exception). I've tried a few values for this, including the tenant with which my app was originally registered and, my logical favorite, "common," but no matter what I put in there (unless it's the tenant I'm trying to log in with, and if my ADAL is set up with that tenant), it seems to just skip over this.

For what it's worth, an actual API call is failing on the `[Authorize]` filter and returning a 401, which tells me this isn't an issue with my OWIN interceptor.

How can I tell `UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication` to support multi-tenant authentication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out while writing the question. I think. But I spent all day on this finding almost no documentation on the matter, so I figured I'd post it anyway.

My solution (found through [yet another blog post](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/10/09/the-use-of-azure-ad-behind-deploy-to-azure/)) was to include `ValidateIssuer = false` as a parameter. This makes sense, since we no longer want to validate that the tenant giving us a token is the one that we've listed.

Here's my code that solved the problem.

```
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
                    ValidateIssuer = false // This line made it work
                },
                AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active,
                Tenant = "common" // I don't know whether this has any impact,
                                  // but it's a required parameter regardless.
            });
```

I'd love if someone else wanted to correct me if this has any unforeseen circumstances--it's a tad daunting flipping a "validate" switch to off when you're working on authentication. But I think this all makes enough sense.

Comment: You should have a look at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs

Comment: Here's a comment around that configuration: instead of using the default validation (validating against a single issuer value, as we do in line of business apps), 
                        // we inject our own multitenant validation logic

Comment: @ken thanks for pointing me to this URL... I was looking for that code. I had seen it in the past but was not able to find it using Google.

Answer (score 2):

When you are developing a multi tenant application, you can no longer rely 100% on the default authentication logic. The default authentication logic assumes that you declare the azure AD tenant form where you want to receive tokens, and will enforce than only tokens form that tenant are accepted. This is done by examining the metadata document associated to every tenant, which contains (among other things) the identifier of the tenant itself - that identifier must be present in the token you receive, in the iss claim: any other value means that the token comes form another tenant, hence it must be rejected.
By definition, multitenant applications must accept tokens from multiple tenants. This is done by using a parametric endpoint (the common endpoint, see [this post](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/08/26/the-common-endpoint-walks-like-a-tenant-talks-like-a-tenant-but-is-not-a-tenant/)) which allows you to "late bind" which tenant will be used to issue a token. However the common endpoint will serve a generic metadata document, which cannot contain a specific iss value: instead, it contains a placeholder that at runtime will always be substituted with the issuer identifier of the tenant you actually got the token from.
This means that in multitenant apps you have to *take over* the tenant validation logic. If you are just debugging you can turn it off, as you appear to have done - that will prevent the default issuer validation logic from kicking in and refusing the incoming token because its iss value does not correspond to the placeholder found for common. In more realistic cases, however, you will write your own logic in the `TokenValidationParameters.IssuerValidator` delegate. For example, you might want to compare the iss value in the incoming token against a list of tenants that bought a monthly subscription to your service. HTH

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. My question wasn't so much on the theory of it all, as it was on the actual mechanics of how that class works to accomplish it. But thanks for the information. Speaking to the actual mechanics, do you know how much of this the OWIN logic will handle? My concern with setting `ValidateIssuer = false` was simply in the *authentication* side of things, I've already got authorization handled. As long as I can be sure that the set issuer is, in fact, the tenant that issued the request, I'm golden.